# DevExpress MVC how to remove padding from GridView cells

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress-mvc

I have a project where I need the data in some consecutive rows to appear right next to each other.  Therefore I need the cell padding and borders to go away, but only for certain columns within the gridview, not all.

How can this be done.  I am using c# .net mvc
Thanks.

**_GridviewPartial.cshtml**

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "ExampleGridView";

    settings.Columns.Add(new Column(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Column1";  
    }));
    settings.Columns.Add(new Column(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Column2";  
    }));
    settings.Columns.Add(new Column(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Column3";  
    }));
}).GetHtml().BindData()
```

Now what I want is for the data in Column2 to have no right border and the data in Column3 to have no left border, so the data will show up right next to each other.  Imagine 2 progress bars that I want to appear as 1 progress bar with 2 sections.

Comment: You need to check what css is being applied to the grid view? And change it accordingly to get your needed styles.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I only want it for cells in certain columns of the gridview tho

Comment: Is there any code that we can see?

Comment: @gavsta707 I added some example code